# Populate HTTP request headers with custom header in .Net Core 3.0 middleware

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to populate request headers with custom headers in middleware? My aim is making calls to external rest api which has basic auth implemented. So it would be nice to keep API secrets in back-end code.

I have tried all methods that possibly could add header to request headers in HTTP context but seems it is a bit harder then I thought before.

There is no problems to modify response headers maybe there is such way with request headers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between modifying requests and responses here.

Since you're calling a rest api you need to inject an `IHttpClientFactory` > Create a client > Add the auth headers to it via appsettings.json (for example)

or

You can use `Typed Clients` which can be configured like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<GithubClient>(c => { c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer", "token"); });
```

You can add your auth headers from the config above using the `DefaultRequestHeaders` property then inject an `HttpClient` in the your typed service which will be responsible for making the calls to your rest api.

Everything about this topic is available in the docs. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Hi HMZ. Thanks for answer. Calls to API will be made with AXIOS from client side. As I see without HTTPClient instance it is impossible...

Comment: @EduardSurovij Well this is a big piece of information to be left out of your question! The safest way is to store the token in the backend and then call an action on your server to make a call to the rest api other than that there is no guarantee for the safety of the token.